# How to fix ad to the screen while in scrollview?

Tags: java, android

The title says it all. I have an scrollview and i want to make my ad "attached" to the display.
Because it doesnt follow and if you start scrolling the view before the app loads when it loads it sends you to the ad which is annoying. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Don't put the ad in the ScrollView.

instead of

```
 <ScrollView>
     <!-- your ad here -->
     <!-- your content -->
 </ScrollView>
```

try something like

```
<LinearLayout>
   <!-- your ad here -->
   <ScrollView>
       <!-- your content -->
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks man! It worked but it is transparent i can see the text behind it. Any ideas ?

Comment: I can see the text behind the ad.My text is bold does that make any difference ?

Comment: Give your view a background color. Take a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view

Comment: It didnt work.I've got an ImageButtons and i have the ad above them but when i scroll trough them i can see the imagebuttons on the ad.
Hope you can help :) and if you know how can i do the save for a textView. Thank you.

Comment: I need help.I tried other things but it is still visible behind it.
And the ad can not be clicked.