# Android: how to change dynamically the button icon color?

Tags: android, button, colors

I have this button in my layout:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/followers_right"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_team"
   android:text="@string/visibility_right_followers" />
```

By default, all my icons are grey. But in some cases, I want to apply a specific color. And for the drawable button, how can I do that programmatically ?

```
myButton.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.tint_selected));
```

This line doesn't work (build error).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set background color of a View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view)

Comment: @hata I think he is trying to get the colors from the values.

Comment: What kind of cases? Are those cases calculated or received from a server? Do those cases depend on user behavior (press, focus etc.)?

Comment: It's not the background color, but icon color

Comment: Sorry, it's not duplicate.

Comment: Can you add the code. and the build error. Can you check the import for the R.

Comment: This code line is just an example what I would like to do : myButton.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.tint_selected));

Comment: Please, see if you can find your solution here. https://github.com/jrvansuita/IconHandler

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution myself for this interesting question but I am not there yet. One work around is have the same icon in different colors as `Drawable` resources,

and change the icon of the button grammatically,

```
yourButtom.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.low, 0, 0, 0);
```

But the only issue is, if you want huge range of color chages