# How do I set color with .setBackgroundColor(); with color from values/colors.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-color

In Android, I'm trying to set a color from res/values/colors.xml

Using `title.setBackgroundColor()`

Currently I can set it with:             `title.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);`

However, I would like to reference a color from the .xml

When I use:

```
title.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
```

referring to:

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Andriod studio reports:

```
Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here: `getResources().getColor(R.color.white)` less... (⌘F1) 
This inspection looks at Android API calls that have been annotated with various support annotations (such as RequiresPermission or UiThread) and flags any calls that are not using the API correctly as specified by the annotations.  Examples of errors flagged by this inspection:
Passing the wrong type of resource integer (such as R.string) to an API that expects a different type (such as R.dimen).
Forgetting to invoke the overridden method (via super) in methods that require it
Calling a method that requires a permission without having declared that permission in the manifest
Passing a resource color reference to a method which expects an RGB integer value.
...and many more.  For more information, see the documentation at http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/annotations.html
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set background color of a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view)

Comment: try to set  `title.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));`

Answer (score 4):

Go to res->values->color.xml and write the code like below:

colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="name_color">#3F51B5</color>
</resources>
```

And to set:

```
title.setBackgroundResource(R.color.name_color);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file :

```
<color name="newcolor">#FF00</color>
```

and use

```
title.setBackgroundResource(R.color.newcolor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.green)`. That will give you the color that you want, by the ID that you pass. In the end:

```
title.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext, R.color.green));
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try in Xamarin**

```
SomeView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.justRed);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add this

```
title.setBackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor));
```

or

```
title.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yourColor);
```