# How to change background color of center element using Snaphelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to change the background color of the centered position element. I have used vertical snapHelper and my center element is also detected so I just want to add background color to the center element.

```
LinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper() {

        @Override
        public int findTargetSnapPosition(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, int velocityX, int velocityY) {
            View centerView = findSnapView(layoutManager);
            if (centerView == null)
                return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

            int position = layoutManager.getPosition(centerView);
            int targetPosition = -1;
            if (layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()) {
                if (velocityX < 0) {
                    targetPosition = position - 1;

                } else {
                    targetPosition = position + 1;
                }
            }

            if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
                if (velocityY < 0) {
                    targetPosition = position - 1;
                } else {
                    targetPosition = position + 1;
                    centerView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                }
            }

            final int firstItem = 0;
            final int lastItem = layoutManager.getItemCount() - 1;
            targetPosition = Math.min(lastItem, Math.max(targetPosition, firstItem));
            return targetPosition;
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register scroll listener to the `RecyclerView`, and when the scroll is over (i.e. it's in `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` state); the `snapHelper.findSnapView()` shouldn't return a `null` value; so you can set its color.

```
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        // Detect scroll end
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

            // Resetting all the loaded items to the default color 
            int firstVisibleItemPosition =
                    layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            for (int i = firstVisibleItemPosition; i <= lastVisibleItemPosition; i++) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                // Rest to the default color of other loaded items
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.defaultColor, null));
            }

            // Changing the background of the snaphelper centered item
            View centerView = snapHelper.findSnapView(layoutManager);
            if (centerView != null)
                centerView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.centerColor, null));
        }

    }
});
```

Kotlin:

```
val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        
        // Detect scroll end
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            val firstVisibleItemPosition =
                layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
            val lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
            for (i in firstVisibleItemPosition..lastVisibleItemPosition) {
                val holder =
                    recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) 

                // Resetting all the loaded items to the default color 
                 holder!!.itemView!!.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.defaultColor, null))
            }

            // Changing the background of the snaphelper centered item
            val centerView: View? = snapHelper.findSnapView(layoutManager)
            centerView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.centerColor, null))

        }

    }
})
```

---

**UPDATE:**

There is a better approach than iterating over all the RV loaded items, to reset to the default color; by just saving the previous centeredView into a local field, and update its color instead of updating the entire loaded items:

```
View previousCenteredView;
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        // Detect scroll end
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

            // Changing the background of the snaphelper centered item
            View centerView = snapHelper.findSnapView(layoutManager);
            previousCenteredView = centerView;
            
            if (centerView != null)
                centerView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.centerColor, null));

        } else if (previousCenteredView != null){
            // Resetting previous centered view to the default color 
            previousCenteredView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.defaultColor, null));
            previousCenteredView = null;
        }

    }
});
```

Kotlin:

```
var previousCenteredView: View? = null
val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        
        // Detect scroll end
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

            // Changing the background of the snaphelper centered item
            val centerView: View? = snapHelper.findSnapView(layoutManager)
            previousCenteredView = centerView
            centerView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.centerColor, null))
            
        } else if (previousCenteredView != null){
            // Resetting previous centered view to the default color 
            previousCenteredView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.defaultColor, null))
            previousCenteredView = null
        }


    }
})
```

Comment: How can I use this in when user is scrolling the rv. Because when I put it in OnScrolled method it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

for setting background color of a view, you can use various methods [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view)

based on you code you are setting the background color of the view but only inside the `if` statement, so try extracting the line to be after the `if` .

```
...
if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
      if (velocityY < 0) {
            targetPosition = position - 1;
      } else {
            targetPosition = position + 1;
      }
}

centerView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);

final int firstItem = 0;
final int lastItem = layoutManager.getItemCount() - 1;
targetPosition = Math.min(lastItem, Math.max(targetPosition, firstItem));
return targetPosition;
...
```

Comment: Application crashed when i used it generating null reference exception

Comment: So i tried centerView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)) instead of that its working fine and how to remove that background color when element is not at center?

Comment: you can set it's background to another color or transparent