# AndroidStudio: Explode animation doesn't work when i set background color to the root layout in the xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-animation

I don't know if it is a bug or i am making some mistake but when i set `Explode` animation when opening an `Activity` it animates like a `Slide` animation from top to bottom. I did some trial and error and it turns out that when i use a custom `background` color in the `root layout` in the `xml` file this unexpected behavior occures. When i remove the `background` color everything works as expected.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here??? Because it is important for me to set `background` color in the `root layout`.

Here's a sample of my `xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#000000"                   // This causes the unexpected behavior.
   tools:context=".ExplodeActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/b" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the `ExplodeActivity` 's `onCreate` method where i am assigning the `animation`:

```
class ExplodeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_explode)

    val enterTransition = Explode()
    enterTransition.duration = 500
    window.enterTransition = enterTransition
}

}
```

Here's the previous activity's code which responsible for starting the `ExplodeActivity`:

```
val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle()
val intent = Intent(this, ExplodeActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent, options)
```

Comment: interesting. Have you tried setting the background color in Kotlin? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view

Comment: i set the background color using `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dt_main_background</item>` in the `style.xml` and it's working fine now.

Comment: nice, then you might as well answer your own question here